# Red Aussie fur color is changing

Tags: dogs

On my, soon to be 2 year old, red Aussie the fur has begun to change to lighter color only in one spot. I'm just wondering, does anyone know why? Thanks for the help.

Here are the photographs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Impossible to tell. This could be just normal "aging" (just like people's hair might change). It could be some kind of infection, but in the end we can't tell (especially with no photo). I'd suggest keeping an eye on it and if you notice anything else (changed, swellings, etc.) or in general, if you worry about it, go to a vet.

Comment: Ya I'm not to sure how to post a picture on here

Comment: Upload it on imgur.com and put the link in your post. Someone with more reputation will embed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Many reasons, could be aging, the sun, if he came in contact with something, hair cuts can also alternate a change in fur texture/colour.

Pictures would definitely help :)

Comment: Looks like normal color change from age. 
Signs for concern would be dry/flaky skin, redness, fur loss, scabs/sores or itchiness to the area.

Comment: Thank you  her tips of her ears are really dry but its been like that her whole life